# How to speed up factory_girl associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot

With the classic blog post example, suppose we have the following models

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  has_many :comments

  validates_presence_of :blog
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  validates_presence_of :post
end
```

When we want to create a comment via a factory, we have to build a blog and post first, even though we don't really care about them in the test.  Over hundreds of tests, this eats up a lot of time.

What are some best practices to keep from creating all of these untested records all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I think for the isolation this factory you have to pretend that the post exist and set the comments.post_id to the fake id for example 1

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :comment do 
    content 'testing text'


    factory :comment_without_post do
      post_id 1 
    end

    factory :comment_with_post do
      post
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using fixtures for parent elements. I usually only set up one or two fixtures per model for this purpose and then feed them in as parent elements for any factory create where the parent is not important.

You should remember that fixture loads will not trigger any validations so depending on how you have your models set up they may actually be invalid. As a result I try not to use these fixtures as subjects of any actual tests.

Cut my run time in half without having to get into the complexity of mocking and stubbing.